# Extract Input parameters from react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, input

My input component receives a `index` props looks like this:

```
renderLibraryInputForm(props) {
    return (
        <Grid>
           <Row>
                <Col xs={6} md={3}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <ControlLabel>Library Name</ControlLabel>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      name={`libraryName${props.index}`}
                      onChange={this.onAddLibraryInputChange.bind(this, `libraryName${props.index}`)}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={6} md={2}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <ControlLabel>Available Status</ControlLabel>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      name={`availableStatus${props.index}`}
                      onChange={this.onAddLibraryInputChange.bind(this, `availableStatus${props.index}`)}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                ...
             </Row>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

onAddLibraryInputChange function looks like this:

```
onAddLibraryInputChange(name, event) {
    let inputFields = {}
    inputFields[name] = event.target.value
    let inputValues = {}
    this.setState({inputValues})
}
```

I have been trying to insert the input fields' values to get an array of objects - the `inputValues` object in the `setState` - which has this shape:

```
[{name: "Sunnyvale", status: "Available", distance: 7}, {name: "Palo Alto", 
  status: " Not Available", distance: 12},  ...]
```

where `Sunnyvale` and `7` is the value of input fields 1 and 3 respectively of the array's index 0; `Palo Alto` and `12` is the value of input fields 1 and 3 respectively of the array's index 1; ...

Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me like you are always setting the state as an empty object in your handler

```
onAddLibraryInputChange(name, event) {
     let inputFields = {}
     inputFields[name] = event.target.value
     let inputValues = {} <-- input values is always an empty object
     this.setState({inputValues})
}
```

why don't you try to set the object directly to the state and use the index?

it seems like you are passing the index to the handler so try something like this:

```
onAddLibraryInputChange(event, index) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
     [index]:{
      'name': name,
      'status':'X',
      'distance':'Y' 
     } 
    });
}
```